# What was the original name of James Blish's "IMT"?

Tags: james-blish, cities-in-flight

In James Blish's Cities in Flight novel, *Earthman Come Home*, what was the original name of the rogue city known as IMT (Interstellar Master Traders)? Did Blish expect that the alert reader would be able to work out what it was from the description of IMT and its "Proctors" given in the novel?

Comment: Comment, not an answer since I'm not certain, but since *Earthman, Come Home* was written first of the series, I don't think so.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests Gravitogorsk-Mars but no source is given and I do not have my copy to hand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The original name of the city known as "the Mad Dogs" was Gravitogorsk-Mars, or at least that is the earliest name recorded.

According to *A Life For the Stars*, Chapter Four: "Schoolroom in the Sky", A history lesson included:

> ...In 2394 one of the escaping cities, Gravitogorsk-Mars, now calling itself the Interstellar Master Traders, was responsible for the sacking of the new Earth colony on Thor V: this act of ferocity earned for them the nickname of 'the Mad Dogs', but it gradually became a model for dealing with Vegan planets...

As it happens, my copy of *Cities in Flight* (1970) happens to have a makeshift bookmark inserted at the page with this history lesson.

Since *A Life For the Stars* is the second novel in fictional order, but the last written, anyone who wants to search though the section of the earliest written novel, *Earthman, Come Home* with the Interstellar Master Traders will probably find a references to the city's original name of Gravitogorsk-Mars.

---

The real city of *[Magnitogorsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnitogorsk)* was rapidly expanded and developed as a steel-making city in the 1930s. The name of *Gravito*gorsk-Mars was obviously inspired by *Magnito*gorsk.

> Magnitogorsk (Russian: Магнитого́рск, IPA: [məɡnʲɪtɐˈɡorsk], lit. '[city] of the magnetic mountain') is an industrial city in Chelyabinsk Oblast, Russia, on the eastern side of the extreme southern extent of the Ural Mountains by the Ural River. Its population is 407,775 (2010 Census).
>
> It was named after Mount Magnitnaya, a geological anomaly that once consisted almost completely of iron ore, around 55% to 60% iron.

Comment: Imagine an entire planet populated by vegans!?  No wonder you'd want to sack them rather than deal with them.

Comment: @dvidback  That's Vegans from Vega II, not vegans.

Comment: Whatever.  My comment is fine as it stands.  Without reference to any book.